# How does aggro work?

Tags: neptunia-rebirth-1

How do enemies and especially bosses know who to target? What can I do to take the heat off a teammate?

Enemies seem all too happy to target people I've just revived, people I've just healed, people who have just healed or people who are close to death, even if they spent their turn doing absolutely no damage. How can I help distribute the damage between my characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general consensus among people who have logged embarrassingly high numbers of hours playing the first Re;Birth game is that the enemy AI doesn't have "aggro" behavior, i.e. the mechanic of being able to get them to change targets by essentially pissing them off.

The enemies seem to follow a much more straightforward algorithm of simply executing whatever attack procedure will push the player closest to a game over, which of course is its main goal.

The order of priority that seems to be followed rather consistently when making the attack decision is

1. killing a party member or members
2. if there's no chance of killing someone, attack whoever is in range that can be brought closest to death. The AI does take back & side attacks into account as well as buffs and debuffs
3. if no party members are in range, use the turn to move toward the best target for the next turn

As a result, your weakest characters are going to be consistently targeted (causing an endless cycle of wasting turns healing), and if any of them are so weak that the enemies can kill them with only a couple attacks you're going to find yourself reviving the same bloody person every round. The only thing you can really do to protect them is try your best to keep them out of range and buff them as much as possible so the enemies will see someone else as weaker.

Comment: @badp - thanks for the the pity-edit on the formatting! Ironically I neglected proofreading because I was engrossed in another game from the Neptunia series.

Comment: No problem, editing each other's posts is part of the formula :)